# Entity Framework Seed Data on complex object with Nullable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to seed a table in my database based on a complex type that has a nullable field.  On insert, this works fine, but when it tries to do a comparison on update, it throws the error below.

Here is my add or update code

[image]

Here is my object with Nullable AccountId

[image]

Here is the error saying it can't compute..

[image]

Here is the view of the product.accountid field in db

[image]

Comment: What version of Entityframework?  Please post your code next time and not pictures,  it looks like its trying to do a comparison between int32 and int32? did you update your models to reflect the DB correctly, just because your DB says it's nullable doesn't mean EF thinks it's nullable, and vise versa you need to make your types match

Comment: @johnny5 I added a view of the accountid field, allow nulls = true so the model matches the db.

Comment: Server Explorer \ Data Connection \ Database name \ Table \ Table name \  Right click \ Design mode to edit allowing null or not

Comment: @TWilly, you need to make sure EF, is aware of the changes from the DB, are you working with an EDMX Model

Comment: @johnny5  isn't EF aware that it's Nullable from setting the type to int?  I'm using code first